# Error 400 Bad Request when deploying Api Platform on Heroku

Tags: symfony, heroku, api-platform.com

V2.6.5

I'm facing a 400 Error bad request when requesting the API after deploying it on Heroku. But I can't figure out why ?

What I did :

- Added Procfile in root of /api
- Added .htaccess in /api/public (via composer require symfony/apache-pack command)
- Defined APP_ENV and DATABASE_URL on Heroku Dashboard app settings
- Added the Postegresql addons on Heroku Dashboard
- Inside /api folder : git init >> git add . >> git commit -m "..." >> heroku create >> git push heroku master
- Sending a GET http request to the /greetings endpoint via postman (response with 400 code error)

This is a brand new api project, I did nothing except the step describe above.

(At first I followed the tutorial in the official api platform documentation using the app.json manifest but it was not taken into account, so I did the configuration in heroku dashboard directly)

Answer (score 0):

On the Procfile, just remove the quotes ''

Before : `'web: heroku-php-apache2 public/'`

After : `web: heroku-php-apache2 public/`

OR

Maybe you should try :
/api/greetings/

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I didn't put quote in the Procfile but it does not work :/